# Running docker with selenium and google-chrome/firefox in normal mode on centos/rhel without guiu

Tags: docker, selenium-webdriver, centos, rhel

I have the impression that I have a non-trivial problem, I searched half the internet and I don't know if it can be done, well, I have machines with rhel without gui. Just server editions and on that machines are installed self hosted azure agents. On the agents, we want to run selenium tests using google-chrome and chromedriver or firefox and its driver, but not in the headless version. Now the question is whether what we want to do is feasible? Because when I search the internet, every now and then I come across a strange error or a left topic. I will only add that the agent is also on RHEL.

I tried to install Xserver on the host and run it but apparently it can't be launched in the background, I tried running xterm to check if this xserver on rhel is working, but I get xterm: Xt error: Can't open display: %s
even if I have DISPLAY set correctly, I have installed many things in Docker, but as I understand it, without X server I will not be able to do what I need.

Comment: "... but not in the headless version." Can you explain what do you **think** this will accomplish?

Comment: In any case, Docker is *like* a headless machine regardless of what host system it runs on, and as such cannot run a display server, such as X-server. You should be able to accomplish what you are talking about using [tag:xvfb] **in your Docker image**, not on the host system (RHEL in your case).

Comment: "... but not in the headless version." my testers do not want to run --headless, thay want full functionality of browser.

Comment: Exactly what browser functionality is missing in the headless browser?

Comment: Preferences are not currently supported in headless Chrome.
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1925